# PHP file becomes completely empty while on server

Tags: php, filemaker

So for some reason, I can upload this solely PHP script onto our server with GoDaddy, it will work fine for a day or two, then it stops working. I had figured out that if I simply re-uploaded the file it started working again. After a couple times this happened I contacted GoDaddy support. After chatting with the GoDaddy support while it wasn't working and we realized that the file was completely empty. Just a 0 byte PHP file on our server. GoDaddy support  said that there's no way it was their fault and that it must be something in my script, but I have no idea what could possibly be deleting all of the code from the file. Here's the full file with some security data changed, maybe you  can spot it.

```
<?php 
//Script to send a questionnaire to a customer from a SalesForce Generated Link.
//Looks for a Client in FileMaker database based off of email address passed from SalesForce.
//If no matching client, creates one with First Name, Last Name, and Email. 
//Creates a Correspondence with the Client Id of the referenced client and Date Sent of 
//Questionnaire using the current day.
//Sends an email with the questionnaire link to be sent. The link includes ID's for both
//the Client and their Correspondence, as well as arrival date, tour name, supplier and region.

//Call FileMaker API and Mailer API
require_once('FileMaker.php');
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('class.smtp.php');

//Pull values from URL to create stored link
$nm = $_GET['name'];
$eml = $_GET['email'];
$arrival = $_GET['arrival'];
$tour = $_GET['tour'];
$supplier = $_GET['supplier'];
$region = $_GET['region'];

//Pull values from URL (encoded with Base64)
$name = base64_decode($nm);
$firstName = substr($name, 0, strpos($name, ' '));
$lastName = substr($name, strpos($name, ' ') + 1, strlen($name));
$email = base64_decode($eml);
$searchEmail = str_replace('@', ' ', $email);

//Decode the Region
$decodedRegion = base64_decode($region);

//Connect to Post-Sales database
$account = new FileMaker();

$account->setProperty('database', 'PostSales');
$account->setProperty('hostspec', 'hostname.com');
$account->setProperty('username', 'ourUsername');
$account->setProperty('password', 'ourPassword');

//Search for Client record
$search = $account->newFindCommand('ClientPHP');
$search->addFindCriterion('email', $searchEmail);
$search->setRange(0, 1);
$results = $search->execute();

if (FileMaker::isError($results)) {
    //Create Client if no client found
    echo'No client found, creating client... <br />';
    $addClient = $account->newAddCommand('ClientPHP');
    $addClient->setField('name_first', $firstName);
    $addClient->setField('name_last', $lastName);
    $addClient->setField('email', $email);
    $result = $addClient->execute();
    $records = $result->getRecords();
    $client = $records[0];
    if(FileMaker::isError($client)) {
        echo 'Client was unable to be created.<br>';
    } else {
        $firstName = $client->getField('name_first');
        $lastName = $client->getField('name_last');
        $email = $client->getField('email');
        $clientID = $client->getField('__clientIDpk');
        echo 'Client ' . $firstName . ' ' . $lastName . 
        ' added with email address ' . $email . '<br>';
    }
} else { //Pulls Client if found
    $client = $results->getFirstRecord();
    if (!FileMaker::isError($client)) {
        $firstName = $client->getField('name_first');
        $lastName = $client->getField('name_last');
        $email = $client->getField('email');
        $clientID = $client->getField('__clientIDpk');
        echo 'Client ' . $firstName . ' ' . $lastName . 
        ' found with email address ' . $email . '<br>';
    } else {
        echo 'No client found. Error: ' . $client->getMessage() . '<br>';
    }
}

//Create Correspondence
$addCorrespondence = $account->newAddCommand('CorrespondencePHP');
$addCorrespondence->setField('_clientIDfk', $clientID);
$addCorrespondence->setField('giftcertificate_code', $gcCode);
$result = $addCorrespondence->execute();
$records = $result->getRecords();
$correspondence = $records[0];
if (!FileMaker::isError($correspondence)) {
    echo 'Correspondence added<br>';
    $correspondenceID = $correspondence->getField('__correspondenceIDpk');
} else if (FileMaker::isError($correspondence)) {
    echo 'Correspondence unable to be added. Error: ' . $correspondence->getMessage() . '<br>';
} else {
    echo 'Something went real wrong creating the correspondence. Try it again.';
}



//Create Questionnaire Link
$link = "http://www.cyclomundo-shop.com/questionnaire.php?clID=" . $clientID . "&coID=" . $correspondenceID . "&arr=" . $arrival . "&sup=" . $supplier . "&tour=" . $tour . "&regi=" . $region;

if (!FileMaker::isError($correspondence) && !FileMaker::isError($client)) {
    //Send email to client requesting that they fill out the Questionnaire
    $sendMail = new PHPMailer;

    $sendMail->isSMTP();
    $sendMail->Host = localhost;

    $sendMail->From = 'info@cyclomundo.com';
    $sendMail->FromName = 'Cyclomundo';
    $sendMail->addAddress($email);     // Add a recipient
    $sendMail->addReplyTo('info@cyclomundo.com', 'Cyclomundo');

    $sendMail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

    $sendMail->Subject = 'Thanks for riding with us!';
    $sendMail->Body    = "Bonjour " . $firstName . ", <br /><br />" .   //Email from Michelle
            "How did you enjoy your cycling trip to " . $decodedRegion . "? Did the itinerary, meals, and accommodations live up to your expectations? <br /><br />" . 
            "We would really appreciate it if you would give us your honest feedback on your entire Cyclomundo experience in our questionnaire — it will take only a few moments for you to complete. <br /><br />" .
            'You may complete our online questionnaire <a target="_blank" href="' . $link . '">here</a>.<br /><br />' .
            "We'll take your comments, both positive and negative, and share them with everyone involved in bringing our trips to life. Your contribution makes a big difference to us at the office, everyone we work with, and all future Cyclomundo travelers — including you, we hope! <br /><br />" . 
            "To extend our gratitude for your contribution, you will be given a gift certificate for a 75 euro discount to be used on a Cyclomundo tour booked by December 31, 2016. This unique certificate can be used for any one of our tours of five days or more. You can keep it for yourself or give it to a friend for a fantastic gift! Please note it cannot be combined with any other discounts we offer. <br /><br />" .
            "We look forward to hearing from you. <br /><br />" .
            "Best regards, <br />" .
            "Michelle <br />" .
            "www.cyclomundo.com";

    if(!$sendMail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $sendMail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        $gcCode = strtoupper(substr($firstName, 0, 3)) . $correspondenceID;
        $correspondence->setField('giftcertificate_code', $gcCode);
        $correspondence->setField('questionnaire_date', date('m-d-Y'));
        $correspondence->setField('questionnaire_link', $link);
        $added = $correspondence->commit();
        if(!FileMaker::isError($added)) {
            echo 'Mail sent to ' . $email . ' and Correspondence updated with the correct Questionnaire Sent Date and Link<br>';
        } else {
            echo 'Mail sent to ' . $email . '. Error updating Questionnaire Sent Date of Correspondence. Error: ' . $added->getMessage() . '<br>';
        }
    }
} else {
    echo 'Mail not sent due to error in Client or Correspondence records.<br>';
}

?>
```

Comment: I don't think the file itself could give us any reason why it's behaving that way, it should be a problem *outside* the file, aka on the server (some script, cron, or I don't know what...)... please somebody correct me if my assumption is wrong...

Comment: *GoDaddy support said that there's no way it was their fault* ... yes because that would be an admission of liability for a poorly implemented security model on their server... that is, of course, if it is something like a *nix user/group configuration error (e.g. another user having access to your files)

Comment: Just in case it is the script overwriting itself it would be useful to know the filename so we could look for something writing to it. But most likely its not the script. **Are you sure you have not been hacked**

Comment: No server file operation, no shell command called, no call to strange user-defined classes which may contain dirty functions => Border effect from an other source which empties it. If you have an ssh access to this repository just suppress the rights to write on this file while you don't have an access to it (chmod is your friend) and when you want to edit it just reassign writing permissions.

Comment: So I changed the permissions to read only for everyone through GoDaddy, hopefully that will fix it but it worries me that our files are vulnerable, going through our server I found another two files that were completely empty. I know this is a pretty broad question but what are some basic things that could possibly be allowing this to be happening?

Comment: He got access to your domain (your ftp/webdav/whatever account) or to the GoDaddy's server itself (and all the domains contained inside it). Don't write in plain text your password + username in your code by the way, the guy may have accessed your DB also

Comment: How should I be hiding the info? I'm pretty new to PHP and figured because it wasn't visible in the source code it was okay to do that...

Comment: Even though I changed the permissions on GoDaddy, it STILL became empty, and I noticed that it was at the exact same time as it did yesterday (9:10AM). Nobody on my team has touched it all day. Any other ideas of what could be happening?

Comment: All incoming data is tainted. I don't see where you're cleaning the data. $_GET could always have some malicious code in there to overwrite the current file and your code is only as secure as the code you wrote. You're assuming the Filemake, phpmailer and smtp objects have no vulnerabilities. Are they all up to date? filter_input is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here is a PHP file that will delete its own contents after two days.

```
<?php
if (time() - filemtime(__FILE__) > 172800) {
    $handle = fopen(__FILE__, 'r+');
    ftruncate($handle, 0);
    fclose($handle);
}
```

I don't see anything in your file that would achieve this, even indirectly.